# Why isn't JTableUsergroup implemented as nested set inheriting JTableNested?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-user-groups

Joomla uses [Nested Sets](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_nested_sets) to represent the category structure `JTableCategory` and the menu structure `JTableMenu`. Therefore these classes inherit the `JTableNested` class:

- `JTableCategory extends JTableNested`
- `JTableMenu extends JTableNested`

Why isn't this concept of Nested Sets also used for `JTableUsergroup`?
The database table `#__usergroups` is prepared to represent a Nested Set but the code of the `JTableUsergroup` class inherits `JTable` and does not use locking for operations nor rebuilds the nested set tree when deleting a user group.