# Why is there no rebuild() function call after deleting a usergroup?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jtable, joomla-user-groups

Examining the class `JTableUsergroup` located in `libraries\joomla\table\usergroup.php` I found out, that the nested set is rebuilt after storing a new usergroup but not after deleting one.

Is this behaviour implemented on purpose and what is the reason for not rebuilding the nested set model?

Answer (score 1):

The question would be if there is a need to rebuild the structure after a deletion.

In my opinion, only new items force a rebuild and usergroup deletion does not require a rebuild.

If you find a case where it does work as expected, it is a bug. You can submit a Pull Request to fix the issue to https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms.

Comment: I even wonder why 'JTableUsergroup' does not inherit the 'JTableNested' class. For this case I have already posted a question some time ago: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12392/why-isnt-jtableusergroup-implemented-as-nested-set-inheriting-jtablenested